# When selecting .ktr file in PRD getting error as "Unable to load class for step/plugin with id [MongoDbInput]"?

Tags: pentaho, pdi, pentaho-report-designer

I have a simple pentaho formation with MongoDBInput connected with JSON Output. I am able to fetch json while i see preview in Pentaho Report Design(PRD) but as I try to integrate with java, and run the transformation, its throwing error -

> org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:  Error reading
>   object from XML file
>
> Unable to load step info from XML step
>   nodeorg.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleStepLoaderException:  Unable
>   to load class for step/plugin with id [MongoDbInput]. Check if the
>   plugin is available in the plugins subdirectory of the Kettle
>   distribution.
>
> Unable to load class for step/plugin with id [MongoDbInput]. Check if
>   the plugin is available in the plugins subdirectory of the Kettle
>   distribution.

Anyone have solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Pentaho Report designer is not identifying MongoDB Input plugin from the kettle transformation you selected.

Make sure you are browsing a right transformation before it is working for you. Also check versions b/w Pentaho Report designer and Kettle.

Advisable: If you installed Whole Pentaho BI suite on your Machine and trying this scenario works well than working with Patches.(Patches means downloading zip folders differently for Kettle and Report Designer)